# How to detect when user returns to app specifically via "Recent apps"?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, androidx

I have my own pin code activity in my app which popup every time user returns to the app (on first start or when the app was in background). I found it curious that some bank apps can somehow detect when user just jumped to another app via "Recent app" and then return to the bank app (in this case PIN activity will not show up in these apps). How did they do it that when returned from Recent Apps, pin code activity will not be triggered?

I tried androidX´s `LifecycleObserve` and `ComponentCallbacks2`.

Currently I´m using `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` to generally detect when user leaves the app, but I have not idea, how to programmatically differentiate these two cases? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I have my own pin code activity in my app which popup every time user returns to the app (on first start or when the app was in background). I found it curious that some bank apps can somehow detect when user just jumped to another app via "Recent app" and then return to the bank app (in this case PIN activity will not show up in these apps).

What makes you so sure they're detecting that you came back from "recent apps"? If you go to a bank app, press back to close the app, then re-launch it from the list of apps, you may not be prompted for a pin or password.

If you leave the app for long enough and come back to it from "recent apps", you may be prompted for a pin or password.

More than likely these apps are employing some kind of time-based heuristic, although this will of course vary by app.

> How did they do it that when returned from Recent Apps, pin code activity will not be triggered?

I don't know how "they did it", but as for the the question of "how can I know my activity was launched from recents"? Try looking for [FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) in your intent.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for the answer....if user did not close the app, but just jumped to another app and he returns to my app (without closing my app), will this flag still be present or its working only when app is freshly started?

Comment: I don't know. Try it and see.

Comment: well it really was like as I said :( ...this flag is contained in the intent only, when the app is ended via back button and then opened again with recent app again

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you should reconsider you requirement of "was the app launched from recents" as that will not paint a full picture. For example, you open your app, user switches to another app, user press home, user opens the app drawer, user opens your app from drawer. If that was less than 30 seconds would you want to show a pin because it was "not from recents"?

Comment: Well it's not really my requirement :) ...it's just behaviour I found in a few apps and I have no idea how the did it... They have the timeout functionality there as well but this keeps me awake at night 